# Doubts with long type detection

Tags: java

This code detects which of the datatypes you can use to store the number that is obtained from the user. If there are multiple suitable datatypes, everything is listed.

However, the code failed to satisfy to properly execute -100000000000000 (which should come under long)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Exception;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;

public class Mainn
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        int size = console.nextInt();
        BigInteger numbers[] = new BigInteger[size];
        BigInteger Long = new BigInteger("9223372036854775808");
        BigInteger Int = new BigInteger("4294967295");
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
            numbers[i]=console.nextBigInteger();
        }
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
            System.out.print(numbers[i]);
                if(numbers[i].compareTo(BigInteger.valueOf(-65536)) > 0 && numbers[i].compareTo(BigInteger.valueOf(65535))<0)
                    System.out.printf(" can be fitted in:\n* short\n* int\n* long\n");
                else if(numbers[i].compareTo(Int.negate()) > 0 && numbers[i].compareTo(Int.subtract(BigInteger.valueOf(1)))<0)
                    System.out.printf(" can be fitted in:\n* int\n* long\n");
                else if(numbers[i].compareTo(Long.negate()) > 0 && numbers[i].compareTo(Long.subtract(BigInteger.valueOf(1)))<0)
                    System.out.printf(" can be fitted in:\n* long\n");
                else
                    System.out.print(" can't be fitted anywhere.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider using `BigInteger.bitSize()` to detect the number of bits required, which is probably a lot easier.

Comment: don't use Long as a variable name.

Comment: Thanks Louis. That function makes the code much simple :)

Comment: `for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
  {
   System.out.print(numbers[i]);
    if(numbers[i].bitLength() > 8 && numbers[i].bitLength() < 16)
     System.out.printf(" can be fitted in:\n* short\n* int\n* long\n");
    else if(numbers[i].bitLength() > 16 && numbers[i].bitLength() < 32)
     System.out.printf(" can be fitted in:\n* int\n* long\n");
    else if(numbers[i].bitLength() > 32 && numbers[i].bitLength() < 64)
     System.out.printf(" can be fitted in:\n* long\n");
    else if(numbers[i].bitLength() > 64)
     System.out.print(" can't be fitted anywhere.");
  }`

Answer (score 6):

Your `Long` is initialized to 2^32-1, which wouldn't fit your example number, whereas [`Long.MAX_VALUE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#MAX_VALUE) has a value of 2^63-1.

Also naming a variable `Long` is a pretty bad idea. It shadows the class [`Long`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html) which is a standard part of the JDK, and it violates [conventions](http://www.cwu.edu/~gellenbe/javastyle/variable.html), which suggest using something like `variableName`.

Comment: Can you please tell my why not to use Long. I'm bit new to coding.

Comment: I agree with @vlad the range of long variables is from [-2^63] to [2^63 - 1], to be precise the range varies from -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807. Also try to avoid naming variables with a reserved keyword.

Comment: Ahh...but i thought case sentivity beats the reserved keyword conflict.

Comment: It's not a reserved [keyword](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html), but it is a class that's always there and people know about. When I first read your code I was looking for a `negate()` method in the `Long` class.

Comment: Oops. Now i understand. Thank you Vlad :)